# Derive a line from two CGPoint

Tags: ios, geometry, algebra, cgpoint

Given two CGPoints, lets say P1 and P2, I would like to:

- find the line that connects them
- find all CGPoints along that line

Any suggestions?

---

As far as now I got the following way to derive the various points:

1) I first of all start from the equation of a line defined as
   following:

```
y = m * x + b
```

2) To find m:

```
m = (P2.y - P1.y) / (P2.x - P2.x)
```

Then, to find b we shall remember the quation of the line and we can apply this to any of the two points we have (P1 and P2), so:

```
b = y - m*x
```

becomes:

```
b = P1.y - m*P1.x (where we have both P1 and m)
```

This equation has an expection, which is the case when P1 and P2 are one above the other (P1.x == P2.x). In this case become an equation where the x does not vary, hence we have only one variable defined by the y part of the point.

[Cit. a good interactive guide to find/derive this type of answer is [here](http://www.webmath.com).]

Comment: Homework? For what you need that for?

Comment: No, I am writing a collision detection method for a laser beam (CCsprite) that ais part of a Cocos2d class with a CCSprite as parent. Using the [CCSprite boundingBox] method was providing me an excessive rectangle when the box was roted. Also, being the laserBeam child of a CCSprite (I had to use CCSprite as I was adding the parent class to a CCSpriteBatchNode) I had to derive a way to locate this in the world space coordinates (so wrote a little method finding the two points at the origin and end of the laserbeam to then compute an array of CGpoints in the line and check if the ship..

Comment: ....ship bounding box contains any of those points (if so there is a collision).

Answer (score 2):

at least this is wrong:

```
m = (P2.y - P1.y) / (P2.x - P2.x)
```

it should be

```
m = (P2.y - P1.y) / (P2.x - P1.x)
```

or better

```
   denom = P2.x - P1.x;

   if (denom != 0) {
     m = (P2.y - P1.y) / denom;
   } else {
     //handle special case
     m = 0;
   }
```

From your comment I see you want to make a collision detection of a line with a rectangualr boundin box.
So i would search for "line and rectangle intersection". The result gives you intersection points: if there is one, the line has hit the bounding rectangle.

Comment: yes thank for the answer. I coded it right and copied it wrongly. My question was about finding an "in built alternative" to this (without having to compute myself the points along the line).

Comment: You dont calculate points along the line, you probably should do it analyticaly: you cut the line with your objects. As you have learned in school (intersection of line with circle, line to line). But these code is available.  (Thus you create intersection points.) you will check

Comment: Yep, but I couldn't find the code to cut the rectangle with the object. I was looking for some primite function to calculate whether there is any intersection between a line and a rectangle and didn't find it, hence I created my own approximation of this. I am using iOS and Cocos2d.